# join tables based on if the ID = 2

Tags: sql, join

I have 3 tables `SP_COMMENTS`, `SP_STEPS`, `SP_TRANSACTIONS`

`SP_COMMENTS` stores comments made about steps that are stored within `SP_STEPS`

Since a comment can relate to multiple steps, I have the `SP_TRANSACTIONS` table that keeps track of all those.

This is how they are related:

```
SP_COMMENTS.SP_COMMENTS_ID = SP_TRANSACTIONS.SP_TRANSACTIONS_COMMENT_ID

SP_STEPS.SP_STEPS_ID = SP_TRANSACTIONS.SP_TRANSACTIONS_STEP_ID
```

What I want to do is display all the comments `WHERE SP_STEPS.SP_STEPS_ID = 2`

I am horrible at determining what kind of join this should be and would appreciate the help - thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT columns
FROM SP_COMMENTS c
INNER JOIN SP_TRANSACTIONS t ON t.SP_TRANSACTIONS_COMMENT_ID=c.SP_COMMENTS_ID
WHERE t.SP_TRANSACTIONS_STEP_ID=2
```

Additionally, I have a few notes on your naming conventions:

- Prefacing table names with "SP" is **bad**, because in the database world the SP abbreviation has another (more significant) meaning: stored procedure.  By using sp as a table prefix, you're really gonna confuse future maintainers of your application.
- Your transactions table is also poorly named.  This table is an *intersection*  between your Comments and Steps tables.  It is not a transaction, which, again, means something else entirely in a database context.

Comment: Couldn't agree more with your extra points on naming. That was the first thing that stuck out to me in the OPs question.

Comment: I agree as well, it is our analyst's naming convention (not trying to throw anyone under the bus), but yes, the transactions table name is my doing. Thank you for the quick response.